# ASP.NET/WebForms - Eval on element's attribute

Tags: asp.net, webforms, eval

Honestly, what is wrong with this?

```
<a id="ViewPRS" runat="server" href='ERPRS.aspx?prsno=<%#Eval("PRSNumber")%>&phase=phase1'>View</a>
```

It keeps giving me this weird rendered html:

```
<a %="" prsnumber")="" href="ERPRS.aspx?prsno=&lt;%#Eval(">&phase=phase1" id="Phase1PRSList_ctl02_ViewPRS">View</a>
```

which I expect to be:

```
<a id="ViewPRS" href='ERPRS.aspx?prsno=TRIAL-00002&phase=phase1'>View</a>
```

But this works fine:

```
<a href='<%#Eval("PRSNumber")%>'>test</a>
```

Here's the value/format of PRSNumber "TRIAL-00002"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A server-side anchor element will url-encode it's href attribute content. It seems that the element recognizes when the property value starts with an <%#Eval... statement, but if it starts with text it blindly encodes the entire string.

You should be able to concatenate the entire value within the server side tag, as shown below:

```
href='<%# "ERPRS.aspx?prsno=" & Eval("PRSNumber").ToString() & "&phase=phase1"%>'
```

Comment: I think you're right, it works on input-tag's value but not on anchor's href. Thanks